# When trying to run Javafx application it opens an empty box

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using eclipse with javafx. I created a project and eclipse generated Main.java and application.css (which is empty). Afterwards i created some .fxml files using the scene bulider. When i try to run the application however, it just opens an empty box without any regard to what I created in the scene builder.

What am I doing wrong?
Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  try {
   BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
   Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
           scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

Testing.fxml:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="524.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children><TabPane prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="524.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Reservierung" />
    <Tab text="Box" />
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
 <Button layoutX="139.1875" layoutY="39.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="175.8125" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0" />
 <Label layoutX="111.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Ergebnisse Reservierung" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="110.0" />
 <TableView cacheShape="false" centerShape="false" layoutY="162.0" prefHeight="308.0" prefWidth="524.0" scaleShape="false">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="RNr" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="85.0" text="Box" />
<TableColumn prefWidth="97.0" text="Von" />
<TableColumn prefWidth="95.0" text="Bis" />
<TableColumn prefWidth="171.0" text="KundeNamen " />
  </columns>
</TableView>
 <Button defaultButton="true" layoutX="299.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" textOverrun="CLIP" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="70.0" />
</children></AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the FXML file to populate the object graph for the application

```
//BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Testing.fxml"));
```